# Replace page meta description in Wintersmith

Tags: pug, wintersmith

I have the following line in the wintersmith `layout.pug`:

```
...  
head
  meta(name='description' content=locals.description)
...
```

I know I can *add* to the head block in my `article.pug` template, something like this:

```
...
block append head
  meta(name='author' content=#{page.meta.author})
...
```

But now I have the `description` meta header twice:

```
<meta name="description" content="The thing from config.json.">
<meta name="description" content="The thing from the individual article.">
```

Is there a way to *replace* a tag in pug template in wintersmith? I want to avoid to actually having to manually add meta tags in each of my templates.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, you can *replace* blocks in a template. You just have to have them named.

So, my `layout.pug` will look like this:

...
head
block metadesc
meta(name='description' content=locals.description)
...

And in my `article.pug` template, I can *replace* that block:

```
// top-level
block metadesc
  (meta name='description' content=article.title)
```

I'm answering the question instead of deleting, because I know I'll forget this for the next year :)